# How to find numbers that only appears once in a string?

Tags: php, strpos

Let's say I have input string

```
String 1 : 1234123
String 2 : 76523752
```

From those string, I'd like to know which numbers that only appears once. So in my case the output should be

```
String 1 : array(4)
String 2 : array(6,3)
```

I'm guessing I'll use `strpos()` for this task but I couldn't get any logical flow to make this happen. Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: what you have tried so far????

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399066/finding-characters-in-a-string-that-occur-only-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boring solution but **[it works](https://eval.in/705356)**!

```
$string="1234123";
$result=array();
foreach (count_chars($string, 1) as $i => $val) {
     if($val==1) $result[]=chr($i);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative:

```
$string = "1235235236";
$res=[];
foreach(str_split($string) as $c) $res[$c]++; 
$res = array_filter($res, function($a){return $a == 1;}); 
var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_keys`, `array_filter`, `array_count_values` and `str_split` functions:

```
$strings = [
    'String 1' => '1234123',
    'String 2' => '76523752'
];

$result = [];
foreach ($strings as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values(str_split($v)), function($v){
        return $v == 1;
    }));
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [String 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [String 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```